# React Native: undefined is not a function (onPress w/ GooglePlacesAutocomplete)

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-google-autocomplete

I am getting this error from the code below:
undefined is not a function
at screens/HomeScreen.js:38:42 in GooglePlacesAutocomplete.props.onPress
at node_modules/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js:270:25 in request.onreadystatechange

- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

`

```
`import { React } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import tw from 'twrnc';
import NavOptions from '../components/NavOptions';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY } from '@env';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setDestination, setOrigin } from "../slices/navSlice";

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white h-full`}>
            <View style={tw`p-5`}>
                <Image 
                    style={{
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        resizeMode: 'contain'
                    }}
                    source={
                        require('../assets/tb-black.png')
                    }
                />

                <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                    placeholder='Where from?'
                    styles={{
                        container: {
                            flex: 0,
                        },
                        textInput: {
                            fontSize: 18,
                        },
                    }}
                    onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                        dispatch(setOrigin({
                            location: details.geometry.location,
                            description: data.description,
                        }));

                        dispatch(setDestination(null));
                    }} 

                    fetchDetails={true}
                    enablePoweredByContainer={false}
                    minLength={2}
                    query={{
                        key: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
                        language: 'en',
                    }}
                    nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch'
                    debounce={400}
                /> 

                <NavOptions />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})`
```

Everything is working with the GooglePlacesAutocomplete except for that error.

Answer (score 0):

can you post your slice code. I had a similar error.
So what was actually causing my error was the omission of 's' in my spelling of 'reducers' in the creation of my slice function. I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).